# slowness on cassandra cluster 4.0.11

Tags: cassandra

We have 5 node cassandra cluster (Memory:256GB, 32 CPU) with all default parameters on  cassandra.yaml file.

It gives correct output for the smaller query(selecting 1-2 hour data) but it fails with bigger queries always with below errors( when selecting more than 4 hours data).

"Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE"
"URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] dropping message of type GOSSIP_DIGEST_SYN whose timeout expired before reaching the network,"

Can you please suggest us some parameters which can help us to run the bigger queries as well.

Comment: Can you update your question with the query that runs slow, as well as the definition of the table that it's querying?